# hive jdbc connection giving out of memory error

Tags: jdbc, database-connection, hive, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I'm just trying to run a sample hivejdbc client program but it's giving me an out of memory error.

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class HiveJdbcClient {
  private static String driverName = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";

  /**
 * @param args
 * @throws SQLException
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
      try {
      Class.forName(driverName);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(1);
    }
    // "jdbc:hive://host:port/dbname"
    System.out.println("going to get connection");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive://titan-edgenode.int.thomsonreuters.com:22/default", "", "");
    System.out.println("got connection!");
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet res;
    // show tables
    String sql = "show tables";
    System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
    res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    if (res.next()) {
      System.out.println(res.getString(1));
    }

  }
}
```

This is the output I'm getting.

```
going to get connection
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readStringBody(TBinaryProtocol.java:353)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:215)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.service.ThriftHive$Client.recv_execute(ThriftHive.java:116)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.service.ThriftHive$Client.execute(ThriftHive.java:103)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:192)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:132)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.configureConnection(HiveConnection.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:122)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:106)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at HiveJdbcClient.main(HiveJdbcClient.java:24)
```

What's interesting about the error is that I run out of heap space after I get the connection. This is unusual since getting the connection itself doesn't require much space right since I am not executing a query or anything like that.

**Edit**

Here's another variant of this stack from another user (changing max heap size did not make a noticeable difference):

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.receiveSaslMessage(TSaslTransport.java:181)
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:288)
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.open(TSaslClientTransport.java:37)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:190)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:163)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:105)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at [myapp]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could increase your heap space. Use command line argument-Xms -Xmx. If that does not fix it then the driver might be buggy.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get past this error by moving to an x64 application.  Win32 never seemed to have enough memory, regardless of how I configured the max heap size for java.